# Rich Text Editor for Java web applications - Read and Write Rich text

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, rich-text-editor

I am in search of a simple rich text editor to use in JSP pages. I should be able to save the entered text along with rich text format in the database. And when retrieved the text back from the database the text should be visible in the saved format.

I have gone through some of the JavaScript/jQuery APIs available on the net. Many are not compatible with Internet Explorer and some of them lack the proper API documentation.

Best Regards,
Chandra.

Comment: You should build one!

Comment: as thomas said u create one or u can use popular rte like tinymce and ckeditor.I have used both and both work fine..

Comment: I have used the rich text editor that is available in https://code.google.com/p/lwrte/. Works fine with my needs including my requirement as in the question (when uploaded to a database/strem, it actually stores the textarea value as HTML text which I can use again for the display).

The only problem is it doesn't work as expected in IE8.

Comment: JSF implementations (RichFaces, Primefaces, ...) already have rich text editor component. This editor works in all major browsers (IE included).

Comment: I have published a blog (http://pmoulich.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/rich-text-editor-for-java-web-apps-using-lwrte/). This implementation works perfectly well in IE 11 and Firefoxv27). Need to check with other browsers. Image pasting into textarea will not work in IE8 and 9.